# trigger case statement issue sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that causes the toolarge column to state yes or not depending on the size value. The problem is the value remains null after a row is input.

```
create TRIGGER very_large
after INSERT on large
BEGIN
SELECT toolarge, size,
CASE
WHEN size > 50 THEN toolarge = 'yes'
ELSE toolarge = 'no'
END
from large;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside your trigger is a `SELECT` statement that does not update the table.
You need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER very_large
AFTER INSERT ON large
BEGIN
  UPDATE large
  SET toolarge = CASE 
    WHEN NEW.size > 50 THEN 'yes'
    ELSE 'no'
  END
  WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

If there is a primary key in the table `large` then replace `rowid` with the name of that column.